# Bar plot from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have a data frame that looks something like this.

```
print (df)
   a      b
0  1   5896
1  1   4000
2  1  89647
3  2     54
4  2   3568
5  2  48761
6  3   5896
7  3   2800
8  3   5894
```

[image]

And I want to make a bar plot. That looks like this.

[image]

I tried with  `groupby.()`but it only prints only one value of 1  one values of 2 etc...

```
a = df_result.groupby(['column1'])['column2'].mean()
a.plot.bar()
plt.show()
```

Would appreciate some guidance how to solve the problem, so I would have all of the values in a chart.

Comment: Sorry, the data is confidential and I don't know how to write it by hand. But when I print df I get data in this format.

Comment: Zero think it is not possible copy sample data, check [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Oh you meant it like that. Sorry for the inconvenience I will keep it in mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think need [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) first for reshape data:

```
a = df.set_index(['a',df.groupby('a').cumcount()])['b'].unstack()
print (a)
      0     1      2
a                   
1  5896  4000  89647
2    54  3568  48761
3  5896  2800   5894

a.plot.bar()
```

[image: graph]

Comment: Yes, exactly. Also improved your question ;)

Comment: Thank you! I think its the second time you helped me now. Really appreciate it. Never heard of cumcount. Will read more about it.

Comment: Apparently I have so much data, that bars are not bars, they are just straight lines and its all just a mess. Anyway I can resize the image big enough that bars would be well presented?

Comment: You can use `a.plot.bar(figsize=(20,10))`

Comment: Still the same. apparently I will have to make my data smaller. Thank you again!

Comment: If I want to downsize data with a = df_result.loc[0:11, [column1', 'column2']] and print it out with your suggestion it gives me an error : ValueError: all arrays must be same length. You maybe know whats causing it?

Comment: @NoobProgrammer - It seems there is no index `0`, so is possible use `a = df_result.loc[df_result.index[0:11], [column1', 'column2']]` ?

Comment: No still the same. Arent 0, 1, 2, 3 indicies there by default?

Comment: @NoobProgrammer - hmm, I cannot see your DataFrame, so hard to know. What is `print (df_result.to_dict('l'))` ?

Comment: Its a bunch of data like this {x:[x1,x2,x3.....xn]}. prior to my question I extracted columns i wanted to plot with a = df_result.loc[: , [column1', 'column2']].

Comment: @NoobProgrammer - It seems problem is in data, is possible create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: I think i figured it out, but your suggestion gives me 1-19(set of indices) numbers on x-axis an column1 and column 2 as bars., but I would like to have values from column 1 on x axis and column 2 as bars, is that possible?